# Is it possible to get a list of all errors for non validated fields?

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I have a question about collecting validation errors using Waterline. For example, I have a User model with 2 required fields. I want to send an empty request and get a list of errors that 2 required fields are missing. Is it possible? Blueprints returns only one error that one required field is missing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Waterline allows logging of [Usage errors](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/errors#?usage-errors). Here's a list of [Validations Rules](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/validations#?validation-rules) that can be implemented and captured by your error log. For empty strings, use `isNotEmptyString: true`.